# Reordenar filas en Mysql

Tags: mysql, css

tengo una tabla en mysql con las opciones de un menu con secciones y niveles 1, 2 y  3, tengo problemas cada que debo insertar, cambiar o reordenar alguna de las opciones, hice una aplicacion para la edicion del menu en donde cambio de lugar las opciones (ver .gif) pero no logro que en la tabla de la base de datos cambie el orden como lo ordeno en la aplicacion.

Mi pregunta es, como ordeno los registros en la tabla (sin cambiar el id) para que queden igual que en la aplicacion? o que otro metodo puedo usar para organizar el menu?

Gracias por sus comentarios.

[image: Reordenar filas]

Answer (score 1):

¿Qué te parece utilizar un campo orden de tipo float que almacene esa información? De esta forma mantienes el id y, con un ORDER BY, recuperas de la base de datos la lista ordenada siempre que la necesites.

Comment: favor de leer [answer], si bien esto puede ayudar al OP, lo idela para el y todos los que consulten esta pregunta será añadir un ejemplo